# Why am I getting a "Task was destroyed but it is pending" error in Python asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I use `asyncio` and beautiful `aiohttp`. The main idea is that I make request to server (it returns links) and then I want to download files from all links in **parallel** (something like in an [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#example-parallel-execution-of-tasks)).

Code:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def downloader(file):
    print('Download', file['title'])
    yield from asyncio.sleep(1.0) # some actions to download
    print('OK', file['title'])


def run():
    r = yield from aiohttp.request('get', 'my_url.com', True))
    raw = yield from r.json()
    tasks = []
    for file in raw['files']:
        tasks.append(asyncio.async(downloader(file)))
        asyncio.wait(tasks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

But, when I try to run it, I have many "Download ..." outputs and

```
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
```

And nothing about 'OK + filename'.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You forgot to `yield from` the call to `asyncio.wait`. You also probably have the indentation on it wrong; you only want to run it after you've iterated over the entire `raw['files']` list. Here's the complete example with both mistakes fixed:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def downloader(file):
    print('Download', file['title'])
    yield from asyncio.sleep(1.0) # some actions to download
    print('OK', file['title'])

@asyncio.coroutine
def run():
    r = yield from aiohttp.request('get', 'my_url.com', True))
    raw = yield from r.json()
    tasks = []
    for file in raw['files']:
        tasks.append(asyncio.async(downloader(file)))
    yield from asyncio.wait(tasks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

Without the call to `yield from`, `run` exits immediately after you've iterated over the entire list of files, which will mean your script exits, causing a whole bunch of unfinished `downloader` tasks to be destroyed, and the warning you saw to be displayed.